# Opening a Excel sheet which is read only

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program which transfers data from an acces database to an Excel Sheet.

The program is written in Excel and is stored in another excel file then where the data is tranferred to

This because the owner is very careful with his data and preferes the code in a seperate file.

He marked the file read Only.

I can open it and write data, but as soon as i close the workbook the changes are discarded.

Is there a way to open the workbook so i can write data to it?

Comment: Use `ReadOnly:=False` when opening the workbook.

Comment: I tried that. but doesnt work  When i open the excel file directly i get a message that the creator has flagged it as read only.   And the file attribute of the sheet is not set to read only.  Its an internel setting

Comment: [Maybe this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changefileaccess)

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with the IT department here, it seems that it is a setting in sharepoint. Wich is managed by the IT department. So there is no solution